Error C4013: "MmCopyVirtualMemory" undefined in KMDF driver
i get the error when i try to compill the code Error C4013: "MmCopyVirtualMemory" undefined; Assumption: external with return type int.here the code:
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
#include "offsetsDriver.h"


#define IOCTL_TRIGGERBOT_READ_MEMORY CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x800, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_TRIGGERBOT_WRITE_MEMORY CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x801, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

typedef struct _KERNEL_READ_REQUEST {
    ULONG ProcessId;
    PVOID Address;
    PVOID Response;
    SIZE_T Size;
} KERNEL_READ_REQUEST, * PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST;

typedef struct _KERNEL_WRITE_REQUEST {
    ULONG ProcessId;
    PVOID Address;
    PVOID Value;
    SIZE_T Size;
} KERNEL_WRITE_REQUEST, * PKERNEL_WRITE_REQUEST;

NTSTATUS TriggerBotDeviceControl(
    _In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    _In_ PIRP Irp
)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    ULONG controlCode = stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    PVOID inputBuffer = Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    PVOID outputBuffer = Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    ULONG inputBufferLength = stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength;
    ULONG outputBufferLength = stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength;

    if (controlCode == IOCTL_TRIGGERBOT_READ_MEMORY) {
        PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST readRequest = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)inputBuffer;
        PEPROCESS process;
        status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)readRequest->ProcessId, &process);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            SIZE_T bytesRead;
            status = MmCopyVirtualMemory(process, readRequest->Address, PsGetCurrentProcess(), readRequest->Response, readRequest->Size, KernelMode, &bytesRead);
            ObDereferenceObject(process);
        }
    }
    else if (controlCode == IOCTL_TRIGGERBOT_WRITE_MEMORY) {
        PKERNEL_WRITE_REQUEST writeRequest = (PKERNEL_WRITE_REQUEST)inputBuffer;
        PEPROCESS process;
        status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)writeRequest->ProcessId, &process);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            SIZE_T bytesWritten;
            status = MmCopyVirtualMemory(PsGetCurrentProcess(), writeRequest->Value, process, writeRequest->Address, writeRequest->Size, KernelMode, &bytesWritten);
            ObDereferenceObject(process);
        }
    }
    else {
        status = STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST;
    }

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = (status == STATUS_SUCCESS) ? outputBufferLength : 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return status;
}

void DriverUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    UNICODE_STRING symLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\TriggerBot");
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&symLink);
    IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject);
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    UNICODE_STRING devName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\TriggerBot");
    UNICODE_STRING symLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\TriggerBot");

    PDEVICE_OBJECT deviceObject;
    NTSTATUS status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &devName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0, FALSE,                            &deviceObject);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&symLink, &devName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        IoDeleteDevice(deviceObject);
        return status;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; i++) {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = TriggerBotDeviceControl;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

I reinstalled the SDK and WDK in the latest version and repaired Visual Studio in the install settings.I also checked if all the settings are correct and if I selected the correct KMDF template. Additionally, I tried manually declaring MmCopyVirtualMemory in the code.but the compiler still recognizes the same error.( Error C4013: "MmCopyVirtualMemory" undefined; Assumption: external with return type int)

The function is intentionally undocumented and omitted from the kmdf headers.  You could perhaps borrow a declaration from here.
